Use the same thickness value in both solidify modifier and material
In the new EEVEE there is thickness input in "Material Output". I would like a way to link the thickness input to the thickness I use in a solidify modifier applied to the same object. This way I do not have to change the thickness twice and if I apply the material to another object with different thickness I do not have to create a different material.
Any idea on how to do that?

For a single object you could use a diver, but if you use the same material on multiple objects maybe establish an attribute https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/275270/use-a-geometry-nodes-instance-attribute-in-the-shader

I'm not sure i understand what to do. I understand i can use geometry node to store an attribute and then i can use the same attribute in the shader and it is working. What I'm missing is how can i use the attribute for the thickness of the solidify modifier.

Depending on the geometry, you could replace the Solidify with a geometry nodes based solution, or you could use a driver to base the Solidify on the attribute. Haven't tested myself but I suspect it should be possible
